# Put search box inside table view in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to place `Search Text Box` inside the table similar in following image.

Through `Search Text Box` we will be able to search items in table through search box.

I am using this example for my table [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nI26FKpdiMpdm1Eu1Cus?p=preview), but this is not according to my requirement.

#### Need some `css` require to improve !

```js
// Instantiate the app, the 'myApp' parameter must 
// match what is in ng-app
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// Create the controller, the 'ToddlerCtrl' parameter 
// must match an ng-controller directive
myApp.controller('ToddlerCtrl', function ($scope) {
  
  // Define an array of Toddler objects
  $scope.toddlers = [
    {
      "name": "Toddler One",
      "birthday": "1/1/2011",
      "happy": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Toddler Two",
      "birthday": "2/2/2011",
      "happy": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Toddler Three",
      "birthday": "3/3/2011",
      "happy": false
    }
  ];
  
});
myApp.directive('multiwareswitchitem', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
              value: '='
          },
          template: '<div>{{value.name}}  <div><small> Birthday {{value.birthday}} </div></small></div>'
      };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.7" data-semver="1.2.7" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
    .switchBox td {
        padding-right: 64px;
    }
    .switchBox .entBox {
        overflow:auto;height:10em; width:300px; border:1px solid #cccccc;  border-radius: 4px;float:left; box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075); padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 10px;focus: {border-color: #66afe9;};
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;

    }
    .switchBox .entBox div:hover {
        background-color: #3875D7;
    }
    .switchBox .entBox:focus {
      border-color: #66afe9;
      outline: 0;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
    }
    .switchBox .eBox2.entBox {
        background-color: #444;
    }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="ToddlerCtrl">
      <table>
        <tr>
            <th>All Toddler*  
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Search City" ng-model="search.name">
           </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="switchBox">
            <td>
                <div class="entBox">                        
                    <multiwareswitchitem ng-repeat="item in toddlers |filter: search" value="item">       
                    </multiwareswitchitem>                        
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
    <table id="table">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search"></td></tr>

   <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>

   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>

   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>

   </tr>
</table>
```

In above example you can see that search box is not inside table, and css is not impressive, **I need table like following image**

[image]

Comment: please show your code

Comment: you mean search icon in search bar ?

Comment: @Venkatraman  no put search box inside table..

Comment: Check the answer with thead and tobody

Comment: @Venkatraman  I update my demo, but it is not look impressive as I want, plz see image ...http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/3785/

Comment: Its not semantic way. check my answer whether it works for you ?

Comment: why you're not using HTML select box with searching support?

Comment: @Venkatraman  I update my question with original requirement, plz see it

Comment: Your target to design your custom select box with filter in AngularJS right?  and you need same design similar like select box what you have shared. you don't want table with filter like https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated Answer after Few discussion:

Use [`AngularJS ui-select`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMSHd.png)

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/wmZw5leDPN6PGcWk260B?p=preview

[image: Angular UI Select]

#### Initial Answer:

Try the below Snippet which is improved version of your code.

```js
var $rows = $('#table tbody tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

```css
body {padding: 20px;}
input {margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 2px 3px; width: 209px;}
td {padding: 4px; border: 1px #CCC solid; width: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th>
       <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
     </th>  
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: same thing I am looking for, but In your example table appears only when I click, how to make table appears without clicking...

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Good example for what you want .. hope it will work for you and you will get what you want..

http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2011/01/03/searching-text-in-a-html-table-using-jquery/

..

http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/support/searchbox.html

Comment: I update my question with original requirement, plz see it